While condition does not break
I have the following code in R, and I believe it should break immediately. Instead it runs until number_of_retries is reached. But trying it manually "status <- run_request_and_writedb()" makes status TRUE, and is.null(status ) evaluates to FALSE, which should break the while loop if not both conditions are met. What am I missing here, or do I fundamentally misunderstand while conditions?
run_request_and_writedb <- function() {
      return(TRUE)
}

  ## Try the function a few times
  # return value is null
  status <- NULL
  # number of attempts at start
  attempt <- 1
  number_of_retries <- 3
  
  while( is.null(status) && attempt <= number_of_retries ) {
    try(
      status <- run_request_and_writedb()
    )
    attempt <- attempt + 1
    Sys.sleep(10)
  }


Are you sure the function call is successful? Try removing try.

It's not a matter of terminating the while loop, but Sys.sleep(10) gives you the illusion that the while loop is endless (unless you are sufficiently patient and wait for 10 seconds).

Description
Suspend execution of R expressions for a specified time
interval.
Usage
Sys.sleep(time)
Arguments
time     The time interval to suspend
execution for, in seconds.

When you remove Sys.sleep(10), you can see that your code exits the loop
## Try the function a few times
# return value is null
status <- NULL
# number of attempts at start
attempt <- 1
number_of_retries <- 3

while (is.null(status) && attempt <= number_of_retries) {
    status <- run_request_and_writedb()
    attempt <- attempt + 1
}

or add break immediately before Sys.sleep(10)
## Try the function a few times
# return value is null
status <- NULL
# number of attempts at start
attempt <- 1
number_of_retries <- 3

while (is.null(status) && attempt <= number_of_retries) {
    status <- run_request_and_writedb()
    attempt <- attempt + 1
    break
    Sys.sleep(10)
}


... Instead it runs until number_of_retries is reached ... I don't think sleep is the issue.

You are correct, it doesn't run till number_of_retries is reached but the sleep command threw me off. Maybe I should get some myself

@user2974951 I think OP is not patient enough till the end of sleep, so it was understood as failure in loop termination.

I was under the impression that a while loop should break immediately, but it finishes the current run.

@Sebastian If you want it to exit immediately, you should state break before Sys.sleep(), see my update
